# A field with dashes in the slug

Tags: database, user-meta, slug

How do I reach a specific userdata in the database, when that field has a dash (hyphen) `-` in the slug?

I use the plugin [WP-Members](http://rocketgeek.com/plugins/wp-members/).

I have created a new userdata field with the plugin with the name `date-of-birth` - by mistake I used these dashes `-` instead of underscores `_`. In the database (the `usermeta` table) it now looks like:

[image: Database screenshot]

I get the userdata with these two lines:

```
$user_data = get_userdata( $user_id );
$user_data->user_email;
```

which works for all fields - exept those with dashes in them! I have tried this:

```
$user_data = get_userdata( $user_id );
$user_data->date-of-birth;
```

which just returns `0`. And this:

```
$user_data = get_userdata( $user_id );
$user_data->date_of_birth;
```

which of course doesn't work (it gives `null`), since that is not the correct name.

Is there a method to reach this field with dashes in the slug?

**Note**
I can't change the slug. That is not allowed by this plugin after the field is created.

Comment: Pure PHP magic (or madness) as per answer, not in scope. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$user_data = get_userdata( $user_id );
$user_data->{'date-of-birth'};
```

It's weird looking but should work. :-)

Comment: Perfect. This works.

Comment: Happy to help...!